# What chord completes this chord progression?

Tags: guitar, chords, chord-progressions, tablature

Not sure how to complete this chord progression in guitar tab. I think the chord on the left is `CaddG` followed by a `Cadd9`. What comes after that?

```
3     3
3     3
0     0
0     2
2     3
3     x
```

I tried the following but it didn't sound right.

```
3
3
2
3
x
x
```

Comment: We can’t tell you what to write. That’s subjective. We can tell you that the first chord is just a G major chord. Not a “CaddG”. Also check out “Closer to Fine” and “Wonderwall” for chord progressions that include your first two chords. Might give you some ideas.

Comment: 'CaddG' can't be right, as G is already part of a C triad.

Comment: The second chord is a c major chord with the 9th added. The D on the B String.

Comment: These two chord form the basis of the Greenday song Time of your life. Pretty common chord sequence.

Comment: @NeilMeyer you’re right. I believe in the song Dmaj is the third chord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first chord is `Gmaj`, and the second is, as you say, `Cadd9`.

Since you're looking to "complete" the progression — i.e., create a cadence:

- A very logical next chord would be `Fmaj`, completing a 2-5-1 root movement.

```
1
1
2
3
3
1
```

- Another option would be the treat the 9 in the `Cadd9` as a suspension from the `G` chord, and just resolve it to `Cmaj`.

```
3
1
0
2
3
x
```

The chord that didn't work,

```
3
3
2
3
x
x
```

most likely didn't work because of the two top notes: D and G. That chord, in this context, is best named `F6add9`, and, because of the 6 and 9, does not create the sense of resolution that a "plain" `Fmaj` chord gives.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and background! I’ll try out the Fmaj and Cmaj tomorrow.

Comment: Aaron, your alternate voicing of the F6(add9) is close to unplayable. At best it’s very awkward and difficult. You have to do partial bars with both the 3rd and 4th fingers. I was actually able to play it but it felt my hand was going to seize up!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm playing the chords in the right order but `Fmaj` didn't seem to resolve the sequence. May be because I couldn't play the full barred chord. Not sure what this chord is but it seemed better `x 0 0 2 3 3`. Not totally satisfying but it did provide some resolution.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Note to self: have a guitar handy before getting too clever. Thanks. I've removed the hand-torture chord.